# Can cgi scripts with permission 775 run under suEXEC?

Tags: apache-2.4, git, centos7, file-permissions, suexec

We have suEXEC installed, and we also use git version control.

suEXEC only allows cgi scripts to run with permission 755. Git sets file permissions on cgi scripts (and all executables) to 775.

Is there a way to configure suEXEC so that cgi scripts can run with permission 775?

Answer (score 0):

Not safely, no. I would fix your git preferences to not alter the permissions.